# How should I compare survival curves of 2+ groups with their own controls?

Tags: r, survival

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly. I tried speaking to a statistician at my University but they use SAS which I haven't used. I'm currently working in R Studio.

I have 4 groups of different mosquitos (Colony) which are treated (1) or untreated (0 (Treatment). I believe I should be matching the treatment with its control within the group before comparing the groups. I'm not sure how to do this. I thought maybe `strata()` but I am not sure if that's the correct approach.

My current code is:

```
coxph(Surv(Time, Status) ~ Treatment*Colony, data =  des1)
```

the output is

```
n= 260, number of events= 260 

                       coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
Treatment            0.9882    2.6863   0.2989  3.306 0.000948 ***
ColonyNGO           -0.1827    0.8330   0.3663 -0.499 0.617915    
ColonyPKT           -1.1924    0.3035   0.3758 -3.173 0.001510 ** 
ColonyTHI           -1.1431    0.3188   0.3991 -2.864 0.004179 ** 
Treatment:ColonyNGO -0.7940    0.4520   0.4190 -1.895 0.058101 .  
Treatment:ColonyPKT  0.1889    1.2079   0.4224  0.447 0.654741    
Treatment:ColonyTHI -0.1192    0.8876   0.4458 -0.267 0.789152    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                    exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
Treatment              2.6863     0.3723    1.4952    4.8261
ColonyNGO              0.8330     1.2005    0.4063    1.7079
ColonyPKT              0.3035     3.2951    0.1453    0.6339
ColonyTHI              0.3188     3.1366    0.1458    0.6970
Treatment:ColonyNGO    0.4520     2.2123    0.1988    1.0276
Treatment:ColonyPKT    1.2079     0.8279    0.5278    2.7642
Treatment:ColonyTHI    0.8876     1.1266    0.3705    2.1266

Concordance= 0.644  (se = 0.02 )
Likelihood ratio test= 73.04  on 7 df,   p=4e-13
Wald test            = 72.18  on 7 df,   p=5e-13
Score (logrank) test = 81.41  on 7 df,   p=7e-15
```

My interpretation of this is that R is grouping all the treated samples together or all of the group together, which is not helpful, but maybe I'm wrong.

EDIT:
#s
Colony Treated=yes n=50
Colony Treated=no n=15

Answer (score 0):

If you have colonies of mosquitos split so that some receive the treatment and the others don't, your model is OK. It looks like you have 35 mosquitos in each combination of `Colony` and `Treatment`. With the Cox model, each of those mosquitos enters the model individually with annotation of its own `Colony` and `Treatment`.*

What you have to watch out for is the interpretation of the coefficients.

With `Treatment = 1` as treated and `Treatment = 0` as control, the `Treatment` coefficient is the difference between treatment and control for the colony that was designated as the reference value of `Colony`. (The R default is the lowest in alphabetical order.) The 3 `Colony` coefficients are differences of the other 3 colonies from the reference colony *under control conditions*. It looks like survival of 2 colonies differs substantially from the reference colony under control conditions.

The interaction coefficients are the *extra* differences between treatment and control for each of the non-reference colonies, versus what you would predict from its difference from the reference colony under control conditions and the effect of `Treatment` on the reference colony. Thus the model does evaluate the difference between treatment and control for each `Colony` individually, as you wish.

If you stratify on colony you wouldn't be able to pick up the difference in survival under control conditions, which seems to be the biggest effect here. A Cox model doesn't return coefficients for predictors within a `strata()` term.

---

*I'm assuming that `Time` of death is recorded individually for each mosquito. If not, you need to talk more with your statisticians about the model.

Comment: Ok so the readout is only comparing to the reference colony? Say Colony A?

yes each mosquito is entered individually with Colony (categorical) and Treatment (num). Should I switch Treatment to categorical as well? (yes/no)
TIme of death is individually recorded.

Comment: @Teragarm yes, each coefficient in your summary is for a difference from the reference colony. Each individual coefficient is the difference under control conditions. Each interaction coefficient is a difference from the combination of control-condition difference and the reference-category `Treatment` effect. With your evidently balanced design you can do `anova()` tests to evaluate overall significance of interactions and control differences among colonies. Tools like those in the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) can do specific comparisons among conditions.

Comment: @Teragarm  with only 2 treatments, numeric coding of `Treatment` as 0/1 is what the software does "under the hood" anyway whether you coded `Treatment` as "yes/no" or "TRUE/FALSE." All types of predictors are converted in some way to numeric for regressions. See this [UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-dummy-coding/) for a standard way that's done with multi-level categorical predictors. With R the `model.matrix()` of your model shows all the numeric details.